Extreme term-functions on ortholattices
Let $L$ be a model of an ortholattice. Given a term in the language of ortholattices, i.e. whose symbols are $\{\vee, \wedge, ', 0, 1\}$, we can construct a function $L^n \rightarrow L$, where I'm abusing notation to use $L$ to refer to the underlying set. I was wondering recently which ortholattices have the following property: there exists a function $f$, constructed via a term, with $\operatorname{im} f = \{0, 1\}$. In general, I'm curious about non-constant non-surjective term-functions, but this is already an interesting special case. (I'm not sure what the proper name for these is called, so I'm going to call them term-functions.)
Here is a non-trivial example of what I mean: consider the term-function
$$B(x, y) = (x \wedge y) \vee (x' \wedge y) \vee (x \wedge y') \vee (x' \wedge y')$$
on the ortholattice $M_4$, i.e. $M_4$ is defined to have atoms $a, b, a', b'$ and nothing else beyond that and $0, 1$. If $x$ and $y$ generate a boolean algebra in $M_4$, then $B(x, y) = 1$. If they don't, then $B(x, y) = 0$.
(This question was inspired by this term I constructed to solve an exercise from Burris and Sankappanavar asking me to prove $V(\{M_4\})$ is congruence-permutable, because I found it surprisingly hard to make these "extreme" term-functions.)
Edit: bolded the question I am asking, because I am worried I didn't make it clear originally. Also linked to what an ortholattice is.
